# LXDE stuck on Login

Tags: login, lxde

Using Ubuntu 14.04, the OS boots to LXDE. I select my username, enter my password, and get returned back to login. I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to log in through the console. I ran `ls -l ~/.Xauhtority` and got back the following:

```
-rw------- 1 a_user a_user 0 some_date /home/a_user/.Xauthority
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to get it working. I ended up deleting whatever hidden files were in the /home/a_user/ directory with the command `rm –rf .??*`.